# Not able to get OAuth token for Magento Rest API Client

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api, oauth

I am using Magento version **1.9.1.0** and server running on my mac and trying to use Magento Rest APIs using OAuth Integration.
I have a **consumer key** and **consumer secret.**

Now, I want to get OAuth token for Rest APIs usage. I have followed this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html)

In this, we needed **`oauth_signature`** and **`timestamp`** which we don't get when we create a consumer on admin panel .

> **Now how can we get OAuth token with only consumer key and consumer
>   secret ?**

Comment: The title says "on OS X" but I don't see anything in your question referring to that fact. What script or software are you using to connect to the Magento Rest API?

Comment: Magento server is running on my mac. Looks like the word  "OS X" is making confusion. I am trying to get and use the rest api from postman client right now. I would be using these api from mobile client as I am able to get them working.

Comment: Your question is too old, but in the Magento documentation is all the flow that you have to create to take the token.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get OAuth Token by using below details:

> URL : https://magento.local/rest/V1/integration/customer/token
>
> Header : Content-Type : application/json
>
> Request Type : POST

```
  **Params**--->
    {
            "email":"test@test.com",
            "password":"test@123"
    }
```

You will get customer token.